# Column getting deleted randomly Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm running an app and for some reason one of my columns keeps getting deleted randomly sometimes from a table in my database.

Is there any reason why this could be happening? There are no Alter statements running. (The backend is a Node.js app)

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any ORM stuff going on in your Node application?

Comment: Postgres doesn't randomly delete columns.  It must be instructed to do so from the application.

Comment: Are you really talking about normal table or materialized view? I have seen similar problem with materialized views.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, we are using TypeOrm for TypeScript, could this be it? Thanks

Comment: Turn on logging in postgresql.conf, log_min_duration_statement = 0 # -1 is disabled, 0 logs all statements